# AWS IAM Role, which allows update/delete of own distributions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-iam

I'm using serverless framework for automated infrastructure provisioning in AWS. For that I want to define a restrictive IAM role, which allows manipulation of own resources only.

For most of AWS services it is possible with a use of a known prefix.
For example for S3 it is:

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:CreateBucket",
        "s3:DeleteBucket",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
        "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::stack-name*"
      ]
    },
```

This rule makes sure, that a user with a role can manipulate only the buckets, which name starts from **stack-name**.

I want to achieve same effect for a Cloudfront distribution, but due to a fact, that I can't define a prefix for it, since the distribution name is completely random, I have to make a restriction like this:

```
{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "cloudfront:CreateCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity",
        "cloudfront:GetCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity",
        "cloudfront:GetCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig",
        "cloudfront:DeleteCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity",
        "cloudfront:CreateDistribution",
        "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution",
        "cloudfront:DeleteDistribution",
        "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
```

This rule looks dangerous, because it allows modification and deletion of Cloudfornt distributions and OAIs, which names are also pretty random.

And if I understand it correct, it is even not possible by design. The only possible value in this case according to [CloudFront API permission Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cf-api-permissions-ref.html) is *

Or do I get AWS docs wrong and there is some way to restrict these actions to allow Update/Delete only of those, which were created by the current user?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what fact prevents "arn:aws:cloudfront::*:distribution/stack-name*" from working? You may want to consider using tags and tag conditions for this instead of resource names.

Comment: You may even want to go a step further and isolate this stuff into different accounts.

Comment: @jordanm condition, you've described won't work, because I can't specify a prefix or any part of a distribution name, when it is created. So, at the end the ARN looks like: "arn:aws:cloudfront::1234567890:distribution/ABCD1234".

Comment: The hint with the tag is very useful and seems to be what I'm looking for. And the hint with an account is also quite a good one, but even then I'd still like to have a restrictive policies, because if an application grows and multiple services are added, I would still restrict rights for every service to kill only it's own resources